# Git - Files Failed to upload during Push

Tags: git, github, push, tortoisegit

I did a bunch of searching on both here and on google and couldn't find the answer to this problem.

I was using GITHUB and TORTOISE GIT.

I created a new repository on GITHUB, and cloned the bare repo on my computer, I then added all the files into the directory for that project, did an ADD, then a COMMIT, then a PUSH.

The problem was that there was 1 folder and all its subdirectories which failed to be pushed to the remote repository, now I cannot PULL those files down to my laptop.

It seems to me that GIT thinks the files are there, knows they should be there, but when a PULL occurs it doesn't download the files that didn't get pushed.

I'm not sure what to do here? There has to be a way to force git to reupload those files? Do I really have to create a new repo to push all the files?

Thanks again for your help, and I'm very sorry if this question already exists.

Comment: Can you see the files in the source tree on Github?  It sounds like you just didn't add that directory.

Comment: No. I added the file, and I cannot +ADD it again because it says its already existing.

Comment: have you tried `git push -f`?

Comment: you can also `fetch` then `merge` and see what's happening (pull = fetch + merge). Fetch should not be a problem if you uploaded correctly. But I would suggest you first answer Jonathan's question, does it appear on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

In TortoiseGit, Tick the force checkbox in Sync Dialog / Push Dialog
to do `git push -f`